# Redirect root to a subfolder with .htaccess, but avoiding conflicts with dynamic URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Here are all my rules, for clarity

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
    # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteBase /
    # Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ignore-this-directory
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !and-ignore-this-directory-too
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cache
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ui
    # don't apply the AI behaviour to images inside AI's cache folder:
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache    
    # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
    # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions
      RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /adaptive-images.php
    # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Add a trailing slash to folders that don't have one
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
      RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
    # Exclude these folders from rewrite process
      RewriteRule ^(admin|ajax|img|inc|js|lang|lib|pub|tpl|ui)($|/)   -   [L]
    # Redirect root requests to /home/ folder
      RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$             /home/                                  [NC,L]
    # Start rewriting rules
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).htm$    /home/details.php?rCat=$1&kParam=$3    [NC,L]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$            /home/master.php?rCat=$1&rCity=$2       [NC,L,QSA]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/$                 /home/master.php?rCat=$1                [NC,L,QSA]
      RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$              /home/page.php?rPage=$1                 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'd like that:

1. typing `www.mysite.com` redirects to `www.mysite.com/home/` directory (no need to show the `/home/` part on the address bar)
2. typing `www.mysite.com/home` (with or without trailing slash) stays in `www.mysite.com/home/` directory; there's a rule in the above list that adds a trailing slash when a directory doesn't have one
3. typing (or clicking a link like) `www.mysite.com/my-category` redirects to a dynamic URL like `/home/master.php?rCat=my-category`

As you can see, `/home/` is the only "real" directory. At the moment, I suspect that the `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$` overwrites the `RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$` despite the `[L]`: when I type `www.mysite.com` seems that I am redirected to `www.mysite.com/home` (and this is fine), but then this URL gets "translated" into `/home/master.php?rCat=home`: since the "home" category doesn't exists, I get an empty category page template.

So, how can I tell .htaccess "don't apply to the /home/ path the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$`, please, but stop to `RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$`"?

Comment: There's `-f` and `-d` for rewriterules - "is this a file" and "is this a directory". e.g. if the url's requesting something that actually does exist in the filesystem, then do something (or don't).

Comment: Yes, I also tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` but no luck: where exactly should I put them?

Comment: somewhere near the top of the rules, most likely, so you don't waste a lot of cpu cycles test/rewriting urls that should be exempted outright.

Comment: Anywhere I place them, they don't work :-(

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home` might work better. explicitly exclude the uris if they start with /home.

Comment: At last I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !home`: your answer pointed me in the right direction, can you give an answer please so I check you as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteRule ^/?$ /home/ [L]

      # Add a trailing slash to folders that don't have one
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
      RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(cache|img|ui)
      RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ /adaptive-images.php [L,NC]

      # skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]

      # Exclude these folders from rewrite process
      RewriteRule ^(admin|ajax|img|inc|js|lang|lib|pub|tpl|ui)($|/) - [L]

      RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+?)\.htm$ /home/details.php?rCat=$1&kParam=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

      RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /home/master.php?rCat=$1&rCity=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

      RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.htm$ /home/page.php?rPage=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

      RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /home/master.php?rCat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```